# Recover /home/ after deleting /usr/lib

Tags: boot, encryption, data-recovery, ecryptfs

I accidently deleted my /usr/lib folder. I had the genius idea of rebooting to see if it still boots. 
Suprise, it doesn't. 
My home directory is encrypted and I don't remember the encryption phrase.

However I can boot into a root terminal and access my files. From there I can even log into my account. So as far as I know you don't need the encryption pw if you are logged into the account that encrypted the files. 
But for some Reason I still only see the "Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop" file in the /home/MYUSER/ . And also when I run the command:  "ecryptfs-recover-private" I'm asked for a recovery passphrase.

All that, even though I'm logged in to my user that encryped the files. Once my UI was still working I never had to enter the recovery phrase.

Is there any way to get back my data without knowing the encryption key but just my User name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a way to recover it. Unfortunately most commands to restore the encryption key or installing packages didn't work from the machine as there were no packages at all. I also used another machine to try accessing the encryption key at /home/$USER/.ecryptfs but I got an error that the key was corrupted.

At the end I installed the same linux version on a new partition, mounted the old one and copied the whole /usr/lib folder of the new installation to the one I crashed.

After that I was able to boot into my system again and I could decrypt all my files with the user password.

Answer (score 1):

You should always backup your encryption passphrase and create a separate backup on an external hd ...

Anyway, I think you didn't delete the key itself. 
You deleted the encfs libraries.

```
find /usr/lib/ | grep encfs
/usr/lib/libencfs.so.6
/usr/lib/libencfs.so.6.0.2
/usr/lib/libencfs.so
```

Your encryption key sould be at:

```
/home/$USER/.ecryptfs
```

or

```
/home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs
```

You need to boot from a live system, mount the home partition with your encrypted home.

For recovery use:

[`sudo ecryptfs-recover-private`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ecryptfs-recover-private.1.html)

It should find the encrypted home, you only need the login password.  Make an external backup after recovery and reinstall your system.